# Making state transitions using xilinx

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, sequential, digital

I am trying to write asynchronous digital system with a very fast clock. The inputs are determined with two switches and a button to allow entering the inputs.Each input determines allows passing to another state. I used the internal clock B8 of digilent basys2 board. I seem to get to the second state correctly but i can't get to other states. The behavioral simulation gave expected results. Here is my implementation,

```
entity states is
Port ( X : in  STD_LOGIC;
       Y : in  STD_LOGIC;
       clock : in  STD_LOGIC;
       input : in  STD_LOGIC);
end states;

architecture Behavioral of state is
    signal FF : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0):="000";
begin
process(clock)
begin
    if(rising_edge(clock)) then
        if(input='1') then
            FF(0)<= (((FF(1)) and (FF(2)) and (not X) and Y) or (FF(0)));
            FF(1)<= (((not FF(0)) and (not FF(1)) and (FF(2)) and X and (not      Y));
            FF(2)<= (((not FF(0)) and (not FF(1)) and (not FF(2)) and X and Y)
                or ((not FF(0)) and (FF(1)) and (not FF(2)) and (not X) and (not Y)));
            Z <= (((not FF(0)) and (FF(1)) and (FF(2)) and (not X) and Y) or (FF(0)));
        end if;
      end if;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

And here is the board assignments,

```
NET "clock"  LOC = "B8"  ;
NET "input"  LOC = "C11"  ;
NET "X"  LOC = "L3"  ;
NET "Y"  LOC = "P11"  ;
```

Why would the simulation gave expected results but tests on the board didn't. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: There are no outputs. How can you tell whether it works or not? Since there are no outputs, synthesis is permitted to trim out everything else, since nothing in the design can affect any output.

Comment: It seems the part which shows that z is the output is not in the code above.Like I wrote before,I am sure my simulation is correct but I cannot get to other states in board.I checked the truth table I wrote for this design  and it also gave the results in simulation

Comment: Your design misses several basic circuits to prepare the input signals for the usage in a FSM. 1) you need to synchronize  all inputs to your working clock domain 2) you need to debounce signals from buttons and switched if the board does not provide apropiate signals. Check your board docu or board schematic file for more infos. 3) sometimes inputs need to generate strobed signals (high for 1 cycle) if so you need an additional edge detection. These steps are mostly needed for all GPIO pins. Another point Xilinx will not recognize your FSM as a statemachine because it's not a typical pattern.

Comment: There are syntax errors. A missing close paren in the rhs expression for the assignment to FF(1), the architecture is of states not state, there is no declaration for Z.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys I ve solved the problem.The simulation worked but the board didnt because in simulation the inputs were given only one time in an rising edge.(I could manipulate the clock with my hand and create a rising edge whenever I want.)But in internal clock B8 the clock changes so fast so it takes my input infinitely many times only in seconds.To fix this I put clock into G12 so that I could give clock with my hand (just like in the simulation)